# Load DNNClassifier in java

Tags: java, python, tensorflow

I learn a DNNClassifier in tensorflow in python. I have 32 floats as input and I have 4  output classes. Here is the program:

```
  training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
      filename=GESTURE_TRAINING,
      target_dtype=np.int,
      features_dtype=np.float32)
  test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
      filename=GESTURE_TEST,
      target_dtype=np.int,
      features_dtype=np.float32)

  # Specify that all features have real-value data
  feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[32])]

  # Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
  classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                          hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                          n_classes=4,
                                          model_dir="./model/")




# Define the training inputs
  train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
      x={"x": np.array(training_set.data)},
      y=np.array(training_set.target),
      num_epochs=None,
      shuffle=True)

  # Train model.

  classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=400)
```

It is the iris modified example, it generate .pb file and this files:

```
checkpoint
graph.pbtxt
model.ckpt-1.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-1.index
```

To predict, with the model I use that function to load the model:
  predictor= tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(exported_path)
With "exported_path" the path to the pb file.

My question is how could I load my model in java. In python I try to load my model with that:

```
with tf.gfile.GFile(filename, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
```

But I get that error:

```
graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

The problem is I don't find the equivalent of tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do what is suggested in ["Using SavedModel with Estimators"](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model#using_savedmodel_with_estimators), which would mean that you export in your Python program using something like this:

```
# Input to the classifier is a batch of 32-element vectors
inputs = {"x" : tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32])}
classifier.export_savedmodel("./saved_model", tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(inputs))
```

And then you have load and execute in Java using [`SavedModelBundle.load()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/java/reference/org/tensorflow/SavedModelBundle)

For example, here's the Python code used to train a model and then export it in the SavedModel format:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[32])]

# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                        hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                                        n_classes=4,
                                        model_dir="./model/")

# Random inputs and outputs here, probably want them from the file
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x": np.random.rand(10, 32)},
    y=np.random.randint(4, size=10),
    num_epochs=None,
    shuffle=True) 
classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=400)

inputs = {"x" : tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 32])}
classifier.export_savedmodel("./saved_model", tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(inputs))
```

And here's the corresponding Java code to load the trained model and execute predictions on it.

```
try (SavedModelBundle model = SavedModelBundle.load("./saved_model/1518198088", "serve")) {
  // A batch of inputs. In real life of course you'd set each row to the actual input you're
  // interested in.
  final int BATCH_SIZE = 1;
  float[][] in = new float[BATCH_SIZE][32];
  try (Tensor<Float> tInput = Tensors.create(in);
      Tensor<Float> tProbs =
          model.session().runner()
              .feed("Placeholder", tInput)
              .fetch("dnn/head/predictions/probabilities")
              .run().get(0).expect(Float.class)) {
    float[][] probabilities = tProbs.copyTo(new float[BATCH_SIZE][4]);
    System.out.print("Predicted class probabilities: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < probabilities.length; ++i) {
      System.out.println(String.format("-- Input #%d", i));
      for (int j = 0; j < probabilities[i].length; ++j) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Class %d - %f", i, probabilities[i][j]));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You might also find the [slides](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vQ6DzxNTBrJo7K5P8t5_rBRGnyJoPUPBVOJR4ooHCwi4TlBFnIriFmI719rDNpcQzojqsV58aUqmBBx/pub?start=false&loop=false&delayms=3000) explaining the TensorFlow model formats useful (linked to from the [tensorflow/models](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/samples/languages/java/) repository. The names of the tensors provided to `feed` and `fetch` can be obtained either from:

1. The command line using `saved_model_cli show --dir ./saved_model/1518198088 --all`, or
2. Using the Java API to parse the model signature information in the `SavedModelBundle`. See slides at [tensorflow/models/samples/languages/java](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/samples/languages/java) and/or [this code sample](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/0652d86/samples/languages/java/object_detection/src/main/java/DetectObjects.java#L96)

The `model_dir` you provide when creating an `Estimator` object in Python writes out the model in a few files - the computational graph in the form of a protocol buffer written out in a human-readable format (`graph.pbtxt`) and some binary files containing the trained weights. You could read those directly from Java, but it means that you''d have to manage parsing the graph and then initializing weights to the trained values by running the "restore from checkpoint" operation.

The SavedModel format packages all this together, so using `SavedModelBundle.load()` in Java does all that for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of that function un c or cpp?